# How to convert byte array to hex string?

Tags: javascript, python

Here is the sample code in JS :

```
function toHexString(bytes) {
  return bytes.map(function(byte) {
      return ("00" + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }).join('');
}

input -> Buffer.from("333138383223633D77DB", 'hex')
output -> 333138383223630770
```

Here is what I have tried so far in `Python`

```
def toHexString(byteArray):
    return ''.join('{:02x}'.format(x) for x in byteArray)


input -> bytearray.fromhex("333138383223633D77DB")
output -> 333138383223633d77db
```

I think the logic is correct but does not know what is wrong

My expectation result of the Python code should be similar to the result of `JS` code.

I would like to ask how should I update the `python` code to get the exact result as `JS` code

Comment: That JS code doesn't really make a lot of sense, the output is different from the input so `toHexString` doesn't do what its name suggests.

Comment: With "wrong" do you mean the JavaScript code or something in the Python code (in the latter case, explain what you expect instead)?

Comment: @ChauLoi but your JS code is broken, it does not output a hex string that is equal to the input.

Comment: The output shown (both variants) are similar. They are not however identical. What do you actually want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Python code is correct (although it can be written much more concise as the other answers suggest), but your JS code isn't because it clearly outputs a hex string that is not the same as the input.

Instead, fix your JS code:

```
function toHexString(bytes) {
  return bytes.toString('hex').toUpperCase();
}

input -> Buffer.from("333138383223633D77DB", 'hex')
output -> 333138383223633D77DB
```

**EDIT**: if you really insist on Python code that outputs the same broken hex string, this may work:

```
import re

input  = '333138383223633D77DB';
output = ''
for m in re.finditer(r'..', input):
    match = m.group(0)
    output += match if re.match('[0-9][0-9]', match) else '0'
print(output)
```

(my Python skills are extremely rusty so it may not work for all inputs, and/or it can be written much more concise)

Comment: I actually expect the response of `333138383223630770`

Comment: @ChauLoi Please explain the logic behind that transformation

Comment: @Pingu I am working on this document https://github.com/loichau1997/Strega/blob/master/ChirpStack-STREGA-CODEC-Decoder.txt

Answer (score 1):

with python 3.5+ you can use `hex()`

```py
def toHexString(byteArray):
    return byteArray.hex()
```

honestly do not think there is any need for defining any helper function when you can just run `byteArray.hex()`

Comment: Well, the question is that the Python code returns the same as the JS code, which it doesn't (because the JS code is broken).

Comment: hi I want to have the response of `333138383223630770`

Answer (score 1):

As has already been stated, there is built-in functionality for this in Python. However, if you insist on re-inventing the wheel then:

```
hs = '333138383223633D77DB'

def toHexString(ba):
    return ''.join([f'{b:02X}' for b in ba])

assert toHexString(bytearray.fromhex(hs)) == hs
```

Note the use of uppercase 'X' in the format specifier.

Also worth mentioning that bytearray.hex() returns a string in ASCII lowercase

Comment: hi I actually want to have the response of `333138383223630770`